# How to create a strip that conforms to the curvature of another part of the object

Tags: modeling

I’m trying to make a treasure chest in blender. I was working on the metal rings that wrap around the led of the treasure chest when I stumbled on a problem with the mesh. Here’s my problem in this screenshot.[image]

The problem only happens when I delete the bottom half. And here is my blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/eeb55cc003f24288b1012da0e63ce90e

(edited) I opened the blend file again and I found out that the normals were messed up. and pressing Shift N don't help.
[image]

Comment: I don't know how to explain the problem.

Comment: I opened the blend file again a found out that the normals are messed up

Comment: I don't know how you managed it, but there seems to be a single face covering the whole of the underside of that ring. If you click on it in face mode and select X - 'Delete Face' it cures the problem.